# Simple element subtraction in nested list if condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list structured like this:

```
mylist = [
    [
        [
            ['1', '2019-12-10 9:54']
        ],
        [
            ['2', '2019-12-10 15:54'], 
            ['3', '2019-12-10 15:57']
        ]
    ], 
    [
        [
            ['4', '2019-12-12 9:51']
        ],
        [
            ['5', '2019-12-12 15:51'], 
            ['6', '2019-12-12 15:53'], 
            ['7', '2019-12-12 15:59']
        ]
    ], 
    [
        [
            ['8', '2019-12-13 15:52']
        ]
    ]
]
```

---

The parent list `mylist` contains 3 elements: `mylist[0], mylist[1], and mylist[2]` . `mylist[0]` contains 2 elements, `mylist[1]` contains 2 elements, and `mylist[2]` contains 1 element.

I would like to subtract two values if a certain condition is met. In this case, it's this:

If an element in `mylist` contains 2 elements (like `mylist[0]` and `mylist[1]` do), I would like to subtract an element from a **previous** list, from an element on this list. More specifically:

Since `mylist[1]` contains 2 elements, it fits the condition, thus the following math should always be done:
`mylist[1][0][0][0] - mylist[0][-1][-1][0]`, which translates to **4 - 3 = 1**.

---

The above operation should be done when any element of `mylist` contains two elements, AKA:

```
for i in mylist:
   if len(i) == 2:
      do the operation!
```

But the operation shouldn't be done on the first element, `mylist[0]`, so it should have a `range(1, len(mylist))`

---

To try this, I used the following code:

```
mylist = [ ... same as above ... ]

subtracted = []

for i in mylist:
    if len(i) == 2:
        math = [float(mylist[i][0][0][0]) - float(mylist[i-1][-1][-1][0]) for i in range(1, len(mylist))]
        for b in math:
            newb = str(b) + "  at  Time:  " + i[0][0][1]
            subtracted.append(newb)

print(subtracted)
```

The desired output is:

```
Desired output:

["1.0  at  Time:   2019-12-12 9:51"]
```

Because we would do an operation with `mylist[1]` (it has 2 elements), but not with `mylist[0]` (it is the start of the list, so it is out of range), and not with `mylist[2]` (it only contains 1 element).

However, I keep getting the following, and I'm not sure why. I've searched the web for the past hour, but failed to find any useful information. Does anyone know what a better script to do this would be?

```
Actual output:

['1.0  at  Time:  2019-12-10 9:54', '1.0  at  Time:  2019-12-10 9:54', '1.0  Time:  2019-12-12 9:51', '1.0  at  Time:  2019-12-12 9:51']
```

**EDIT:** If there was another element `mylist[3]` that contained 2 elements within, the math would still be done (even though `mylist[2]` has 1 element... so the previous element's length doesn't matter), where the number from `mylist[3]`, which let's say is 9, would subtract the number from `mylist[2]`, giving: `mylist[3][0][0][0] - mylist[2][-1][-1][0] = 1.0`.

Comment: Why do you have strings in the lists if you want to operate on them as numbers?

Comment: @Barmar I Barmar, that's just how I got the data. I have to convert the strings back into integers or floats to do math operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use enumerate to iterate over you list and start from index 1 in the list and setting the start value as 1. This will then loop over the items in the list from index 1 and onwards and you can then use the index to refer back to the previous list by subtracting one from the current index.

```py
for index, sub_list in enumerate(mylist[1:], 1):
    if len(sub_list) == 2:
        this_val = int(mylist[index][0][0][0])
        prev_val = int(mylist[index - 1][-1][-1][0])
        result = this_val - prev_val
        print(f'{this_val} - {prev_val} = {result}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4 - 3 = 1
```

Comment: Excellent answer, did exactly what I was looking for! I added a few more elements to mylist, and it works!

Comment: Won't `enumerate()` return indexes starting at `0`, not `1`? So `index` is the previous index.

Comment: you can pass a start value that will start the index from that and increment it by one, So in my code i pass to enumerate the elements from index1 onwards and start the index count from 1. the signature for enumerate is `enumerate(iterable, start=0)` So passing `enumerate(mylist[1:], 1)` will enumerate over the items from index 1 on and will start the index count from 1